# When use the barryvdh/laravel-dompdf , Login is not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf

I used barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) to my Laravel 5.2 project and it worked for me to generate pdf but now I can't log in to the system after I logged out. Its not showing any error and redirect to login page when I try to log in. Could you please help me to resolve this.?

Comment: Do you use version control? It's unlikely that installing dompdf would break login. 

Try to checkout revision before that install to confirm this was the actual reason.

Comment: I didn't use version control. but i had a backup and i tried 3-4 times to install the dompdf. but this problem is generating all the times.

Comment: Do you have anything interesting in logs maybe? 
So far it's hard to tell anything.

Comment: Thanks. I used DomPdf without barryvdh/laravel, then solve the problem.